# PHP is_array returning false?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have used is_array many times. 
The variable is an array, see my code,
but when i use is_array function it returned false

Any Ideas?

Here is my code.

```
public function updateCategories($array = null)
{   
    echo gettype($array); // echos array
    if($array = null)
    {    
        return false;
    }    
    if(!is_array($array))
    {      
        echo "false"; // echos false
        return false;
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        foreach($val as $Property => $Value)
        {
            if(!$this->updateCategoryProperty($key, $Property, $Value))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `if($array = null)` is not comparing, but assigning.

Comment: WOOOOW i cant believe i missed that, i went over my code many times. Thank you very much.

Comment: Exactly. Your editor should have pointed that for you. I use Netbeans, and it gives me a warning when I do assignments inside if statements. You should try it.

Comment: This is common mistake to avoid it write the if statement like this if(null == $array) so if you missed '=' php will throw syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Russel Dias answer: always write your "null-checks" in this way:

```
if (null == $my_var)
```

now, if missing one "=", this will always get a real error, because you cannot assign something to null.

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but why would my "null-checks" always be written this way? Why not `empty( $my_var ) || !is_array( $my_var )`, leaving the obvious fact that it's shorter.